# MySQLSyntaxErrorException when trying to insert a value containing '

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, jsoup

I know there are countless entries already for MySQLSyntaxErrorException errors, but I haven't yet read any posts that have solved my issue, and I could really use an extra set of eyes to try to point out where I'm going wrong.

I'm working on creating a simple web scraper that stores the names of breweries listed on a wikipedia page into a basic MySQL table stored locally using WAMP.  My existing code seems to be working correctly until I encounter a brewery name that includes a ' in the name.  This is also my first time using JSoup for HTML parsing.

Here's my current code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Main {
public static DB db = new DB();

public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, IOException {
    db.runSql2("TRUNCATE Brewery;");
    processPage("myBrew");
    System.out.println("done parsing");
}


// recursive method to find brewery names by adding db entry for all <li><a>
// values on site. Might not need recursion for this.
public static void processPage(String bName) throws SQLException,
        IOException {
    // check if the given URL is already in database
    String sql = "select * from Brewery where name = '" + bName + "'";
    ResultSet rs = db.runSql(sql);
    if (rs.next()) {
        // do nothing because already exists
    } else {
        // store the brewery to database to avoid parsing again
        sql = "INSERT INTO  `Crawler`.`Brewery` " + "(`name`) VALUES "
                + "(?);";
        PreparedStatement stmt = db.conn.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        stmt.setString(1, bName);
        //stmt.execute();
        stmt.executeUpdate();

        // get useful information
        //research this further to better understand what it's doing
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_microbreweries").get();

        //case-senstive
        if (doc.text().contains("Brewery")) {
            System.out.println(bName);
        }

        // get all links and recursively call the processPage method
        Elements breweries = doc.select("a[href]");
        for (Element link : breweries) {
            //System.out.println("element class: " + link.nodeName());
            //System.out.println("parent class: " + link.parent().nodeName());
            System.out.println("element title: " + link.attr("title"));

            //assumes that all brewery names will be listed in <li><a> html format
            if (link.nodeName() == "a" && link.parent().nodeName() == "li") {
                System.out.println("recursive call tripped");
                String tmp = link.attr("title");
                //String first = tmp.charAt(0) + "";
                if(tmp.contains("'")){
                    String brew = tmp.replaceAll("'", "\\\'");
                    /*System.out.println("new string: '" + brew +"'");
                    processPage("'" + brew + "'");*/
                    System.out.println("new string: " + brew);
                    processPage(brew);
                }
                else {
                    if (tmp.contains(" (page does not exist)")) {
                        String brew = tmp.replaceAll(" (page does not exist)", "");
                        System.out.println("shortened string: " + brew);
                        processPage(brew);
                    }
                    else {
                        //no ' exists in the name
                        processPage(tmp);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

When using this syntax, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's All Natural Brewing Company'' at line 1
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:939)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3878)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3814)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2478)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2625)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2547)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2505)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1370)
at DB.runSql(DB.java:26)
at Main.processPage(Main.java:57)
at Main.processPage(Main.java:95)
at Main.processPage(Main.java:105)
at Main.processPage(Main.java:105)
at Main.processPage(Main.java:101)
at Main.processPage(Main.java:105)
at Main.processPage(Main.java:101)
at Main.processPage(Main.java:101)
at Main.processPage(Main.java:105)
at Main.processPage(Main.java:105)
at Main.processPage(Main.java:105)
at Main.processPage(Main.java:105)
at Main.processPage(Main.java:105)
at Main.processPage(Main.java:105)
at Main.processPage(Main.java:105)
at Main.processPage(Main.java:105)
at Main.processPage(Main.java:105)
at Main.processPage(Main.java:101)
at Main.processPage(Main.java:105)
at Main.processPage(Main.java:105)
at Main.processPage(Main.java:105)
at Main.processPage(Main.java:101)
at Main.processPage(Main.java:105)
at Main.processPage(Main.java:105)
at Main.main(Main.java:17)
```

With this code, the brewery name containing the ' is NOT getting stored in my MySQL table.  However, if I replace the following line

```
String brew = tmp.replaceAll("'", "\\\'");
```

with

```
String brew = tmp.replaceAll("'", "\\\\'");
```

then the brewery name DOES get stored into my MySQL table and I get the following error before the next brewery name gets scraped:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'Beau\'s All Natural Brewing Company' for key 'brewery_name'
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:932)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3878)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3814)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2478)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2625)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2551)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2073)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2009)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5094)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1994)
at Main.processPage(Main.java:67)
at Main.processPage(Main.java:95)
at Main.processPage(Main.java:95)
at Main.processPage(Main.java:105)
at Main.processPage(Main.java:105)
at Main.processPage(Main.java:101)
at Main.processPage(Main.java:105)
at Main.processPage(Main.java:101)
at Main.processPage(Main.java:101)
at Main.processPage(Main.java:105)
at Main.processPage(Main.java:105)
at Main.processPage(Main.java:105)
at Main.processPage(Main.java:105)
at Main.processPage(Main.java:105)
at Main.processPage(Main.java:105)
at Main.processPage(Main.java:105)
at Main.processPage(Main.java:105)
at Main.processPage(Main.java:105)
at Main.processPage(Main.java:101)
at Main.processPage(Main.java:105)
at Main.processPage(Main.java:105)
at Main.processPage(Main.java:105)
at Main.processPage(Main.java:101)
at Main.processPage(Main.java:105)
at Main.processPage(Main.java:105)
at Main.main(Main.java:17)
```

Using

```
String brew = tmp.replaceAll("'", "''");
```

instead of

```
String brew = tmp.replaceAll("'", "\\\\'");
```

results in the same issue.

My runSql method from my DB class:

```
public ResultSet runSql(String sql) throws SQLException {
    Statement sta = conn.createStatement();
    return sta.executeQuery(sql);
}
```

If anyone has any ideas, please let me know.  I've spent hours trying different variations of escape characters, etc, but I can't find anything to fix this issue.  Another pair of eyes looking over my code might just be what I need.  Thanks in advance for your help.

**EDIT:**
I'm not currently using Spring or Hibernate.

Comment: Thanks to @Andreas, I was able to fix this issue.  If anyone encounters a similar issue, I changed String sql = "select * from Brewery where name = '" + bName + "'";
  ResultSet rs = db.runSql(sql);to String sql = "select * from Brewery where name = ?;";
  PreparedStatement ps = db.conn.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
  ps.setString(1, bName);
  ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

Comment: Remove second parameter to `prepareStatement()`. The `RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` should only be used on `INSERT` statements where the primary key is auto-generated, e.g. `IDENTITY`, `SERIAL`, `AUTO_INCREMENT`, `SEQUENCE`, ....

Comment: @Andreas Drivers should ignore `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` for select statements (as in: it should just work).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Actually, drivers are *required* to ignore it ([*This parameter is ignored if the SQL statement is not an INSERT statement*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)). However, I didn't say you *can't* specify it, I said you *shouldn't* do so. It useless; and it is misleading to any readers of the code.

Comment: @Andreas Sorry for my imprecise use of should instead of must ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you already know how to use a `PreparedStatement` with value markers (`?`) for the `INSERT` statement, why not use one for the `SELECT` statement too?

*That* will fix your error the correct way.

Comment: That worked.  Thanks for that.  Now it's on to the next series of issues ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use PreparedStatement for both queries, you won't have to worry about replacing quotes and your select will behave consistently with your insert. right now, it seems that the select does not match the brewery just inserted, but the insert fails because of the duplicate name.